# Codeigniter ajax post data error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

why doesn't my ajax execute? I have checked the controller and the model and they were fine.
The problem is the main ajax which is :

```
function updateTable()  {
var count = document.getElementsByName('chk[]').length;
var academic = document.getElementById('cb_AcademicYear').value;
var acyear = academic.substr(0,4);
var sem = "SE00"+academic.substr(5);
var yearlevel = document.getElementById('cb_Yearlevel').value;
var acstart = "";
var acend = "";
var atstart = "";
var atend = "";
var status = "";
var successCount =0;
var ele = "";
var data = "";
for (i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    if(document.getElementById('chk_'+i).checked)
    {
        ele = i+"[]";
        acstart = document.getElementById('acstart_'+i).value;

        acend = document.getElementById('acend_'+i).value;

        atstart = document.getElementById('atstart_'+i).value;

        atend = document.getElementById('atend_'+i).value;

        status = document.getElementById('cmb_'+i).value;

        var postData = {
            'acyear' : acyear,
            'sem' : sem,
            'yearlevel' : yearlevel,
            'acstart' : acstart,
            'acend' : acend,
            'atstart' : atstart,
            'atend' : atend,
            'status' : status
        };

        $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url()?>academicCalendar_entry/update', 
        data: postData ,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data){
            successCount++;
        }
        });
    }
}
alert("Successfully inserted ("+successCount+") data(s) including: "+count+ele+acstart+acend+atstart+atend+status+"\n"+academic+acyear+sem+yearlevel+"\n\nand this is the link for the jquery : <?php echo base_url()?>academicCalendar_entry/update/");
```

}

I put the postdata as an array, which suppose to be fine. But I didn't put it as a json datatype. Do I have to put it as a json datatype? In the error console, I see no error message but it still didn't execute to the database.

can anyone solve this??

Edited on 12 Dec 2012 :
this is my update() function in my controller :

```
function update()
    {
        $academic_year = $_POST['acyear'];  //trim($this->input->post('acyear'));
        $semester = $_POST['sem'];          //trim($this->input->post('sem'));
        $yearlevel = $_POST['yearlevel'];       //trim($this->input->post('yearlevel'));
        $acstart = $_POST['acstart'];           //trim($this->input->post('acstart'));
        $acend = $_POST['acend'];               //trim($this->input->post('acend'));
        $atstart = $_POST['atstart'];           //trim($this->input->post('atstart'));
        $atend = $_POST['atend'];               //trim($this->input->post('atend'));
        $status = $_POST['status'];         //trim($this->input->post('status'));
        $auditname = "Admin";
        $auditactivity = "U";
        $audittime = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->load->model('calendar_Model','cm');
        $this->cm->updateAcademicEntry($academic_year,$semester,$yearlevel,$acstart,$acend,$atstart,$atend,$status,$auditname, $auditactivity, $audittime);
        return true;
    }
```

I have tried using the $this->input->post, with trim, and with $_POST(), but none of them solve it.

And this is where I put the updateTable() func :

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_save" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="updateTable()"/>
```

This is my updateAcademicEntry() func in Model :

```
function updateAcademicEntry($academic_year,$semester,$yearlevel,$acstart,$acend,$atstart,$atend,$status,$auditname, $auditactivity, $audittime)
{
    $data = array(
                'Tahun_Akademik'=>$academic_year,
                'Tanggal_Mulai_Akademik'=>$acstart,
                'Tanggal_Akhir_Akademik'=>$acend,
                'Tanggal_Mulai_Kehadiran'=>$atstart,
                'Tanggal_Akhir_Kehadiran'=>$atend,
                'Status'=>$status,
                'NamaAudit'=>$auditname,
                'AktivitasAudit'=>$auditactivity,
                'TanggalAudit'=>$audittime,
                'ID_Semester'=>$semester,
                'ID_Level_Year'=>$yearLevel
                );
    $this->db
            ->where('Tahun_Akademik',$academic_year)
            ->where('ID_Level_Year',$yearLevel)
            ->where('ID_Semester',$semester)
            ->update('trkalenderakademik',$data);
}
```

Comment: Please add your controller's content.

Comment: what do you get in the success function of the ajax? What do you get in alert()?

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems you're not taking into account that the success callback is ran asynchronously, so your `alert()` call will prolly run before it.

Comment: Chrome > Developer Tools > Network > XHR bottom right, that will show you what is being sent and returned via the AJAX call, you can troubleshoot it that way.

Comment: Are you using htaccess to remove index.php? If no, you're building the url wrong.

Comment: can you please post the block of code where you call the `updateTable` function?

Comment: And considere use `url: '<?php echo base_url("academicCalendar_entry/update")?>';`

Comment: @Raphael_ : the alert was suppose to be a test whether the successCount is working and to count how many data(s) are there which had been sent by the ajax.

Comment: @Jai : same as above the alert() is only to notify that each variables are correct and that the ajax is functioning properly

Comment: @Rick Calder : Thanks man.. i'll try it later on

Comment: @DamienPirsy : i have a .htaccess file and it is configured properly so i don't have to insert a index.php/ every time I call a function

Comment: @manix : okay i'll post the controller ASAP

Comment: OMG, never mind. I was so stupid. Thanks to @RickCalder I was able to find out that my Model has a wrong attribute.. So stupid. Thanks a bunch guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible problems:

1. There is an error in your controller. In which case you have to change it.
2. You mean to add the alert in the callback. Currently the alert runs if the function works or not. 
   Also since the ajax runs async to the alert the alert will not have update value of `successcount`

   ```
   $.ajax({
     url: '<?php echo base_url()?>academicCalendar_entry/update', 
     data: postData ,
     type: 'POST',
     success: function (data){
        successCount++;
        alert("Successfully inserted ("+successCount+") data(s) including: "+count+ele+acstart+acend+atstart+atend+status+"\n"+academic+acyear+sem+yearlevel+"\n\nand this is the link for the jquery : <?php echo base_url()?>academicCalendar_entry/update/");`

      }
   });`
   ```

Comment: The alert was meant outside the callback, only as a notification that the ajax and the loop is working. Each loop represents a checkbox, and if that checkbox is checked, then the ajax will run. Otherwise it will not. It might be in my controller, because all the variable when it runs does shows on the alert. So either the ajax or the controller-model.

Comment: OMG, never mind. I was so stupid. Thanks to @RickCalder I was able to find out that my Model has a wrong attribute.. So stupid. Thanks a bunch guys...